# custom filter in experience profile faceted search

Tags: experience-profile

I have hosted two sites in single sitecore instance. Is it possible to add a custom 
filter in the experience profile faceted search to getting the contact details of each site separately.

Comment: Have you found a solution or alternative to this, I guess Experience Profile data is managed via a pipeline which we could extend to filter on whatever facet we need to (either a custom one or based on existing domain data), a limitation would be if  issue would be if there is any activity data which is not filterable by domain. but seems like a long shot